# How to Show and Hide text in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS, so I can imagine my question is very elementary. However, I was unable to find an answer when looking on the internet.  I have an existing SSRS report with the following section:

Results: [ResultDate]
Name: [Name], DOB: [DOB]

Currently, if we do not get a name or dob the value is blank but the Name: and DOB: still show up.  How do I change the report so if Name is null or DOB is null then hide Name: DOB: else show Name: DOB: ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is all in a text box? If so, constructing your text as a string should do the trick. Make the text box display an expression like:

```
="Results: " & Fields!ResultDate.Value & IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Name.Value)=False, "Name: " & Fields!Name.Value & ", DOB: " & Fields!DOB.Value, "")
```

That expression should only show Name and DOB if there's actually a name. If this is in a Tablix, the process would be a bit different.

Comment: This is pretty close to what i want. I implemented and realized if one field is null then all the fields disappear. I want to only hide fields that are null and always show those that are not. Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and i think i figured it out.

I **right clicked** on [DOB] => went to `expression` => `changed text` from

```
 "=fields.Weight.value"
```

to

```
"=IIF(fields.Weight.Value="","", "DOB:" + fields.Weight.Value)"
```